# iphone: reloading webview with rotation

Tags: iphone, webview, orientation, rotation

i'm using uiwebview to display a very basic html page with just text. i want to support landscape and portrait orientations but i'm having a problem with resizing when the orientation changes. specifically, when the iphone is rotated to landscape, it zooms in on the text (i want the text size to remain the same and for it to fill the wider horizontal space). when it is rotated back to portrait, the text returns to the correct size but now it flows off the page to the right.

i think the solution is to reload the page with each change in orientation. is there a way to reload the page each time the iphone is rotated?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `reload` on the web view when the view controller receives either of these methods:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

You could try setting `scalesPageToFit=NO` in the web view.  You have fairly fine grained control of the webview from the html.  Look at the  [viewport](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) and other meta tags you can use.